# No implicit conversion in template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void f(T a, T b)
{
    ;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    double b;
    f(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I know it won't work because of the template argument deduction which doesn't allow implicit conversions, but I would like to now why it was made like that in c++? Where there any reasons for it ?

Comment: Who should be converted to what?  That can be a very hard answer to obtain.  Instead it is left to you to figure out by adding a extra template type and deciding which one to use.

Comment: @NathanOliver +1 And OP see also upcoming C++17 template auto specifier point (8) in the list http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: Note that you can avoid the problem by calling `f<int>(a, b)` or `f<double>(a, b)`, depending on what you want the code to do.

Comment: Or, be explicit. `f(static_cast<double>(a), b);`

Comment: Thanks that's all I wanted to know